# Jquery callback function executes multiple times

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a popup div like confirm to show like below

```html
<div class='pop'>
    check me
    <span class="spok">Ok </span>
    <span class="spcancel">cancel </span>
</div>
```

Now this popUp will be open on some condition, and on button click I want to return some values to parent function

I am able to call back the function but....
When I tried to hide the popup it alerts as many times it has been called. Select Yes or no in dropdown then after click on Ok or cancel, two or three times, you will see effect

```
function showpop (onclose){
   $('.pop').show();
    $(".spok").click(function(){
        onclose('OK');

    });
    $(".spcancel").click(function(){
        onclose('CANCEL');
          $('.pop').hide();
    });   
}

$("#slt").change(function(){
       var retval = showpop(function(retval){
                   $('.pop').hide();
    if($("#slt").val() == "yes")
        ImYes();
        else
          ImNo(); 
       }).done(function(){

       });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

}); 

function ImYes()
{
alert('I am yes');
}
function ImNo()
{
alert('I am No');
}
```

Find full code here

http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/gp5emrm4/8/

Comment: please put your problem code in the question itself, not just in a fiddle. Questions should be self contained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing the event handler each time you call `showpop`:

```
 $(".spok").click(function(){
        onclose('OK'); 
 });
```

It obviously results in multiple appearances of alerts .

Don't do it:

- Either initialize it once in the `ready` function.
- Or check whether the handler has been already set.
- Or remove the handler after each use.